# images not displayed when iOS app run on device

Tags: ios, image, device

When I run my application on my device, the images are not displayed.

When in simulator mode the images are displayed.

I receive no copy error messages or any other kind of alerts when I run the app on my device.

Any ideas?

Also the images in question are in a paged UI Scroll view, which was coded using the following tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

The Paging with UIScrollView section of the tutorial.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start by verifying that you have imported images for the correct resolutions. You may for example, have only added retina images that work in the retina simulator, but not on a low res test device.

Additionally, you may want to consider deleting the images from your project and re-adding them making sure to select both the "add to target" and "copy files" check boxes on the import prompt.

Edit:

Another possibility is that you've made a capitalization error when referencing your images in code. It is important to keep in mind that the simulator is not case sensitive to these things, but the real device is. For example, if you're image is titled "Image.png" you must reference it exactly that way.

Comment: I agree. I cannot tell you how many times I have forgotten to link the images into my project and wondered why my images were not showing up!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried re-adding with both check boxes selected with no result. Also the images in question are in a paged UI Scroll View. Other images across the app have loaded on simulator and device.

Comment: @user2512523 can you verify the images are not nil at runtime?

Comment: @0x7ffffff how can i verify this?

Comment: @user2512523 NSLogs of the reference to the image, also see the edit to my post for another possibility.

Comment: @0x7fffffff Thanks mate! it was the referencing that was causing the images not to load :)

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. Is there any additional tip?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is struggling with this, what I needed was to delete the contents of my derived data folder. (In Xcode 7: **Window** → **Projects**, go to your project and hit **Delete...** on the far right.)